# Need help to export non - input field in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am working in node.js project ... i have lot of input field in form but i also have user name which is coming after login ... the code i am giving i have put static input... i am able to export input field using below code but not the static fied

```
exports.assessment = (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
```

assessment.hbs:-

```
 <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fullName">User Email </label>
                            <h4 name = "UserEmail">jugal@yahoo.com</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fullName">Team/Project Name </label>
                            <input type="name" required class="form-control" name="TeamName" id="fullName" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter full project name" >
                            <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your team/project name.</small>
                          </div>
```

So as you see in html .. i am able to export input field which is "TeamName" but not able to export "UserEmail" ... i need help for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texts in name `UserEmail` can't be detected with `h4` tag because it's not `input` type. `form` tag allows passing data to the requested URL with `input` tag. So `h4` tag should be `input` tag and then the email address should be put.
from

```
 <h4 name = "UserEmail">jugal@yahoo.com</h4>
```

to

```
<input name = "UserEmail">
```

Comment: @jacobkin It will not solve the purpose i want Usermail should be coming from db which i will do .... so it will not come as a input from user....

Comment: @jugal You mean the email address in h4 tag will be changed by DB? Of course there is a way to use export the email address with another approach.